# Chai Assert, Validating the Text of a Button

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js, chai, assertions

Newbie here, trying to use Chai to validate that the text of a logInButton = Entrar. 
The test runs and passes visually but it keeps failing.

0 passing (73ms)
  1 failing

```
 AssertionError: expected 'logInButton' to equal 'Entrar'
  + expected - actual

  -logInButton
  +Entrar
```

Code:

```
var assert = require('chai').assert
logInButton = 'Entrar'

assert.strictEqual('logInButton', 'Entrar');

err(function () {
assert.notStrictEqual('logInButton', Entrar);
 }, "Expected 'logInButton' to equal 'Entrar'");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are comparing two different strings which obviously will result false. You might wanna remove the quotes surrounding "logInButton" because you want the value of the variable and not the string "logInButton" itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with `node.js`, but I think you want something like this:

```
assert.strictEqual(logInButton, 'Entrar');
```

With:

```
assert.strictEqual('logInButton', 'Entrar');
```

you are comparing two strings - 'logInButton' and 'Entrar', which of cource are not equal.